# "SCRIPT5: access denied" Message in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm receiving the following error in Microsoft Edge (version 20.10240.16384.0):

```
SCRIPT5: access denied message in edge
```

Here is my code:

```js
function getFrame( width, height ) {
    document.getElementById( this.contentid ).style.display = "none";
    this.frame = eval( this.editorid );
    return this.frame;
}

function init( width, height ) {
    this.frame = this.getFrame( width, height );
    this.doc = this.frame.document;  // <-- error
    // ~~~
}
```

The parent and child domains are both the same. Also, Edge doesn't appear to support `eval`.

Comment: Can you link us to an online resource that shows the issue?

Comment: I found an error in this code. :  textarea.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, textarea);

Answer (score 1):

The access denied message here is because you are trying to acccess the iframe.

Comment: I found the problem and fix of this issue. Because Edge doesn't support 'document.charset'.